# Use Windows Terminal in place of cmd when a command line exe is executed

Tags: windows-terminal

I have a couple command line apps (launch4j + java.exe) I use.

I'd like to run them on Windows Terminal instead of cmd.exe. But, even after installing Windows Terminal, when I execute the launch4j exe, it still runs on cmd.exe.

If I run `wt myapp.exe -oneinput` it works, but I'd like to run myapp.exe directly.

Is there any setting I must do so that Windows Terminal is used in place of cmd.exe?

Comment: See [this (negative) answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557629) on SU, where the question would fit better, anyway.

Comment: Tnx, I searched for it and was unable to find, then I found the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-terminal tag. Very sad that it's not possible. I wish launch4j would have that option :D

Comment: Bookmark [Change Windows OS to support default terminal \[defterm\] #492](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/492) and keep fingers crossed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Terminal team are working to enable Windows Terminal to become the default command-line user experience on Windows.

Stay tuned to the [Windows CommandLine Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/) for news and updates on up-coming features.